# How to find the matrix $A$ in this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

The question is given below:

> [image]

But I do not know how to solve it, if my understanding correct, I see that they want us to find the matrix $A$ in the following homogeneous system $AX = 0$, am I correct? if so, then I still do not know how to find the matrix, could anyone help me in this please? If not, could anyone tell me how to solve this problem please?

Thanks!

Comment: Specific details of the space aside, this is essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3374418/265466 and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

The nullity is $3$, hence the rank has to be $5-3=2$.

Hence $A \in F^{2 \times 5}$. Let me write $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1^T \\ a_2^T\end{bmatrix}$ and let the $3$ independent vectors in the solution space be put in a matrix $X$.

$$AX=0$$

means that

$$X^TA^T=0$$

Try to solve the system in $GF(13)$,

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c} 2 & 1 & 9 & 7 & 4 & 0 \\ 8 & 3 & 10 & 5 & 12 & 0 \\ 7 & 6 & 2 & 11 & 7 & 0\end{array}\right]$$

The solution would help you to reconstruct the matrix $A$.

Comment: So my idea was correct that we want to calculate the matrix $A$?

Comment: why did you take the transpose?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to compute $A$. I take the transpose because I find that most people are more familiar to solve for $Ax=b$ rather than $x^TA^T=b^T$.